# Question about the algebraic number theory proposition 2.2

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I was reading Proposition 2.2 in chapter I of Neukirch , which states the following for an extension of rings $A\subseteq B$:

> (2.2) Proposition. Finitely many elements $b_1,\dots, b_n\in B$ are all integral over $A$ if and only if the ring $A[b_1,\dots,b_n]$ viewed as an $A$-module is finitely generated.

if $w_1,\dots,w_r$ are generators of $A[b_1,\dots,b_n]$ and b is any element in $A[b_1,\dots,b_n]$,then 
how can i multiply $bw_i$ and why $bw_i$ is contained in $A[b_1,\dots,b_n]$

In my opinion, $bw_i$ is multiplied by the ring product(because $b$ and $w_i$ are elements in ring B) then Can i make sure that  $bw_i$ is contained in $A[b_1,\dots,b_n]$?

Answer (score 0):

How does the elements of $A[b_1,\dots,b_n]$ look like?

$A[b_1,\dots,b_n]={f(b_1,...,b_n)|f\in A[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]}$

What are $w_i$'s?

$w_i=f_i(b_1,b_2,...,b_n)$ for some $f_i\in A[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$

Again $b=g(b_1,b_2,....,b_n)$ for some $g\in A[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$

Therefore  $h=g\cdot f_i \in  A[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$ implies

$bw_i=h(b_1,...,b_n)\in A[b_1,\dots,b_n]$.

Comment: to explain this background the purpose is that ring of integer forms ideal
                               so $b_1$ is a zero of  monic polynomial of $A[x]$ 
(for example $b_1 ^r+a_1 b_1^{r-1} + ...a_r=0$  where the $a_i$ 's are elements in A )
so $A[   b_1  ]$ is a A-module generated by $b_1, b_1^2 , ...b_1 ^{r-1}$  and inductively $A[b_1, ..., b_n ]$ is finite  generated                                                                         
Conversely, let $w_1,..,w_r$  be  generators in $A[b_1, ... b_n]$ the $w_i$ are elements in $A[b_1, ... b_n]$

Comment: The proposition you stated is true in general for any integral extension B over A ( a commutative ring with 1) . And I know the back ground as well . There is nothing special with the integers here . And $bwi$ is always in $A[b_1,b_2,b_3...b_n]$ for any $b,wi\in A[b_1,b_2,b_3...b_n]$. There is nothing special about b and wi being integral or generator

Comment: i miss that $b$ is any element in $A[b_1,...,b_n]$ i see $bw_i$ is operated by the product of  ring $B$  so   $bw_i$ in $A[b_1,...,b_n]$ .  is it right?

Comment: You see b is an element of $A[b_1,..b_n]$ and w_i is a one of the generator.w_i generator implies $w_i\cdot 1$ is in $A[b_1,..b_n]$

Comment: Is is okay now ?if not let me know

Comment: thank you for your help from korea